# Limit place autocompletetextview to cities only

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

I'm using google place autocompletetextview, I followed the tutorial and it works just fine.
By now I get a list of suggested result but there is no filter for cities, and most of the suggestion are streets name.

My question if there's a way to filter the street names so the result list will include only cities.

Heres my StringBuilder code:

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:il");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `(cities)` type collection in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I tried the third example there (the one that pointing for cities only) and it says  "status" :"REQUEST_DENIED". Thats actually not because of my api key since the first and second do work with the same api so that's kinda wierd...

Comment: It's because they forgot to include the sensor parameter in that third example.

Comment: Works great, the request should be like that : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=YourInput&types=(cities)&language=YourCountry&sensor=true&key=YourAPIKey. By now the top results are from my country but it also includes cities all over the world, do you know what else can be considered as "Country paramater" instead of "language" that in the request?

Comment: You can return `components=country:il` to your request parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Google Api for get cities details.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Chen&types=(cities)&key={Your_ApiKey}
```

So Insert the below line in your code

```
sb.append("&types=(cities)");
```

Full code:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:il");
            sb.append("&types=(cities)");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

Happy Coding :)